# PowerShell get directory of a program

Tags: powershell, directory

I recently wrote a script and want to share it with my colleagues. It’s a simple copy and paste program that creates log-files after each run. The problem is that I used this:   `start transcript -Path C:\Users…`

The program works fine but if anyone else runs the script it won’t be able to create log-files, since the directory is a copy of mine.

Now to my question: Is there anyway that the program can find out the directory where each user saved the script so it can create a sub-folder in that directory and then dump the logs in there?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to the folder containing the currently executing script can be obtained through [the `$PSScriptRoot` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#psscriptroot):

```
Start-Transcript -OutputDirectory $PSScriptRoot
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I record PowerShell sessions using the **Start-Transcript** cmdlet. It creates a log file, where the script is run from.

```
#Log File Paths
$Path = Get-Location
$Path = $Path.ToString()
$Date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss"
$Post = "\" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss") + "-test.log"

$PostLog = $Path + $Post
$PostLog = $PostLog.ToString()

#Start Transcript
Start-Transcript -Path $PostLog -NoClobber -IncludeInvocationHeader

#Your Script
Get-Date

#End Transcript
Stop-Transcript -ErrorAction Ignore
```